# How to accept unformed request xml message in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, messageformat, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb 4.8.1,
So my client is sending unformed xml like below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <r:valid xmlns:r="http://webmail.w3school.com/use">
         <r:user xsi:type="xsd:string">admin</r:user>
         <r:password xsi:type="xsd:string">admin</r:password>
      </r:valid>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <s:Payload xmlns:s="http://www.w3school.com">
  <s:request>
  <s:name>henry</s:name>
  <s:value>2345</s:value>
  </s:request>
  </s:Payload>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In above request **xsi** Prefix namespace has been not declared So its giving error like below in wso2esb server.

```
 TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-01-25 20:42:50,774] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request  {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,41]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?r:user&xsi:type&xsi
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:459)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:279)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        t java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:ParseError at [row,col]:[4,41]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?r:user&xsi:type&xsi
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:336)
```

Its an attribute so they are not declaring any namespace for that.
        **at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:ParseError at [row,col]:[4,41]
    Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?r:user&xsi:type&xsi**

How to diable the xml validation in wso2esb or how would i process this kind of messages,If I declare namespace its working fine,But my legacy sysytem is not sending this where in other ESB same request working fine.

I have tried with changing different message builders in axis2 file with Http,NHttp transports.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**You can achieve this using custom axis2 message builders**

1. Write a custom message builder which implements
   org.apache.axis2.builder.Builder
2. The custom message builder should implement the following method

   public OMElement processDocument(InputStream inputStream, String contentType, MessageContext messageContext) throws AxisFault
3. Implement your custom logic in this method, in your case you can
   safely   replace the xsi:type (hope your soap request is not a rpc
   encoded style of request otherwise you have to declare a xml
   namesapce)
4. Create a jar file for your custom message builder and drop it in
   **%wso2esb-home%\repository\components\lib**
5. Modify the axis2.xml configuration file in
   **%wso2esb-home%\repository\conf\axis2** to accept your custom builder
   by wso2 synapse engine

   ```
   <messageBuilder contentType="text/xml" class="builder.CustomSoapBuilder" />
   ```
6. Finally restart the wso2 esb server to get reflect your changes.